# load whole html script in php file

Tags: php, html, templating

Advance apologies for this noob question but i have to do it perfectly. I have made a website which are all html files and all are working fine. Now for the session handing i have to convert all the html files into php like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  Body elements
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

to something like

```
<?php
  "SESSION HANDLING PHP CODING"


  echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      Body elements
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>'
?>
```

Hoping for best possible solution.
Thanks

Comment: 1) How it is related with phpmyadmin tag? 2) What sessions have to do with the HTML?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to show the html according to the session active..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do an echo, just close the php tag with "?>":

```
<?php
//CODE
?>

Your Html Stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't have to do that - you can mix HTML and PHP easily. Just surround the code with `<?php` and `?>` tags:

```
<?php /* handle session here */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  Body elements
  <?php echo $something_you_handled_earlier; ?>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @PRASANTH that means that you have something wrong with your PHP code (perharps `$something_you_handled_earlier` doesn't exist, it was only meant to be an example). Turning on debugging in your PHP/web server settings is a good idea in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to refer [session handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) in `PHP`.

And then separate the logical php part from the HTML part as mentioned in other answers.